# Multi-Language Site: Cookie or URL Element

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I am making a dynamic multi language web site with CodeIgniter.

**How should I make the navigation between the languages?**

The most elegant solution is to use cookies when the visitor clicks the flags, and remember the decision for maximum possible period and give him the translated language strings. The URL will be the same for every language. Just the content and the meta tag will be different according to the selected language.

The other way is to have language fragment in the URL like /en/ /fr/ /es/ ...

What's the best practice for this, for SEO optimization and stability?

Comment: Not everyone has cookies enabled, so using language fragments in the URL is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice for SEO is to have it in your url string /en/ /fr/ /es/. Else your website will only be indexed in one language, or some pages in one language, and other in another language.

It is better to have every different content (page+language) on a different page to avoid confusion by search engines.

It is also good practice to set the language in your meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="EN"/>
```

Comment: Okay, you convinced me to use /en/ /fr/ /es/ in the strings, so I will do the web site that way. Thanks for the answer :)